# How to enable -webkit-animation/transition-property for :before and :after pseudo elements?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, pseudo-element

How to enable `-webkit-animation` for :before and :after pseudo elements?

You can see in http://jsfiddle.net/4rnsx/ that it is not working for :before and :after.
And here I am trying to enable this feature with Mootools http://jsfiddle.net/6bzCS/.



*Mozilla* - will support it in Firefox 4 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transition-property
*W3C* - CSS3 supports transition-property for all elements, :before and :after pseudo elements http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-property



**Update:** How to enable `fadein`,`fadeout` for CSS3 tooltip http://css-plus.com/2010/04/create-a-speech-bubble-tooltip-using-css3-and-jquery/ and [demo](http://css-plus.com/examples/2010/04/speech-bubble-tooltip/)?

Comment: sorry but why do you want to do the fade as a proprietary browser prefixed filter? mootools does provide a perfectly viable cross-browser way of fading elements in and out, check out `element.fade()` on the mootools docs.

Comment: mootools `el.fade()` does not work for :before and :after pseudo elements

Comment: hrm, good call. can't seem to use a selector to retrieve the :before element - interesting question ++ and yes, i am sure you can refactor it but that's not the point is it.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff - Do you think there is some solution for :before and :after?

Comment: i don't think so, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started/Content - content through css does not become a part of the dom. looks like you may need to refactor or use motools-more's tips.js

Comment: mootools-more's tips.js adds additional tags, so it does not look so nice.

Comment: you can style it any way you want. total css control etc. i was even working on the tips.js demos for the new docs but due to my father's passing have not had time to complete much... can put up some examples on jsfiddle with css3 styling i was playing with. but yes, i personally don't use tips.js in my work

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff - do you have some example for CSS3 tooltip fade?

Comment: yeah but this sort of delayed / fade in behavior is not working too well in older versions, check the fade fixes ticket i raised a while back: https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/24057/tickets/340-tips-creation-injects-element-into-dom-too-early#ticket-340-1 - so you'd need the grab the latest patched tips.js - or have a look at this fiddle using the code from github i just put together: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/5CRUZ/4/ or http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/5CRUZ/5/

Comment: Thanks! Hope it will help me. Do you have also some example for tooltip with image in it?

Comment: certainly. you can use the text: override to pass on how the tips data is being defined and template it or use element storage: http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/5CRUZ/6/ still .tip-text and .tip-title .tip-top and .tip-bottom are totally stylable via css

Comment: btw, view on FF due to gradients being unique there.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look forward for most featured browser issues.

Comment: another test which prove this failure: http://jsfiddle.net/f3GMG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsFiddle mentioned in the question appears fine in modern Chrome and Safari browsers. I think the animation side of thing's been solved by browser evolution.

However, there's still an outstanding/open bug for the transition side of things:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54699

Comment: You are right. I opened that webkit issue and seems it still will not be fixed on Chrome 18. So shame that the issue was opened since Chrome 6.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is fixed in Google Chrome 24 on January 3rd, 2013.

Waiting for Safari to pull these updates.

[See how things are doing with other browsers here](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)