# Applying WebKit transitions to Pseudo Elements

Tags: css, webkit, pseudo-element

I have made a Fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/xypQY/

Which element would i apply WebKit transitions on to achieve a Fade In effect using opacity?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. http://jsfiddle.net/xypQY/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable -webkit-animation/transition-property for :before and :after pseudo elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855079/how-to-enable-webkit-animation-transition-property-for-before-and-after-pseud)

Comment: possibe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798010/css-transitions-with-before-and-after-pseudo-elements

Comment: Dear moderators, I've found about 10 duplicates of this question :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a webkit bug, transitions do not work in Chrome or Safari on pseudo-elements.

Please star this bug to hopefully help the ball get rolling on a fix:

[Issue 54699:   CSS3 transition not applied for pseudo elements](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=54699)

It has been reported to Webkit:

[Bug 23209 - Transitions and animations do not apply to CSS generated content](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23209)

so hopefully it will be fixed soon.

**UPDATE:** Support for transitions was added to Webkit on 01/02/2013: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/138632

Comment: It seems that but still persists in Safari, but there's a workaround: http://kizu.ru/en/pseudos/

Answer (score 4):

At last the bug is fixed in Google Chrome.

You can start using `transitions` on pseudo elements, most Chromes have already updated as on January 24, 2013.

Waiting for Safari to pull these updates.

[See how things are doing with other browsers here](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/)