# CSS Transitions with :before and :after pseudo elements

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, pseudo-element

Can't seem to animate pseudo elements with -webkit-transition. The fiddle below shows what I mean when run in Chrome/Safari, I guess this isn't supported right now?

http://jsfiddle.net/4rnsx/130/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed in Google Chrome on January 3rd, 2013.

By now (I do update this list) it's supported in:

- FireFox 4.0 and above
- Chrome 26 and above
- IE 10 and above

Waiting for Safari and Chrome for Android to pull these updates.

You can [test it yourself in your browser](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lBIxu), or

See the [browser support table](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/).

Comment: it's actually not fixed on production, only development. means that still, you cannot do this in Chrome.

Answer (score 52):

Well, actually, you can.

You just need to leverage the often forgotten `inherit` value.
Unfortunately we can't (yet) directly target pseudo-elements with custom animations, but we surely can let them share the same animation of the "parent" element by inheriting the properties we wish to animate.

See my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/4rnsx/228/).

Comment: This is the most under-appreciated answer of this question.

Answer (score 9):

[Nope, not supported yet](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23209)