# Pseudo element extends the main element. Can I animate the background of the main element anyway?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to animate the background with `transition`?

Unfortunately, the `transition` to the `a` element doesn't work.

```css
.gf-lbtn {
  background-color: #fdce03;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 16px;
  padding: 1rem;
  &:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.gf-lbtn-icon-animated {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.gf-lbtn-icon-animated:after {
    content: '\f178';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    right: 1rem;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    }
.gf-lbtn-icon-animated:hover:after {
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    right: 0rem;
  }
```

```html
<a class="gf-lbtn gf-lbtn-icon-animated" href="#" target="_self" role="button">Hover Me</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Transitions with :before and :after pseudo elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798010/css-transitions-with-before-and-after-pseudo-elements)

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? "animate background" could mean way too many things

Comment: You are either trying to transition the appearance of the pseudo element, not the anchor - previously answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798010/css-transitions-with-before-and-after-pseudo-elements) ... or you need to set the background of the anchor to another value if you want to transition it.

Comment: The problem is changing position relative to absolute