# Why doesn't my :before class transition at all? Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have code that causes a shadow to become visible, however it is not responding to any form of transition for appearing/disappearing.

Can anybody help?

[image]

**CSS for the actual application**

```
.wrapper {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      transition: all 2s;
    }

    .wrapper.shadow:before {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 6px -3px rgba(252, 29, 0, 1);
      pointer-events: none;
      content: "";
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 2s;
    }
```

Please see my extended code [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vzwyma)

**Edit**
[updated fiddle with "inhert" being used](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vzwyma)

Comment: error line 1 : `unexpected token (` (on the Codepen demo)

Comment: How can nothing be transitioned? The JS shows the .wrapper.shadow:before class is being toggled... I have tried this with more standard CSS classes and it works with delays, I just think it is because of the :before tag.

As for the "unexpected token", I'd just ignore that. And do remember that this is POLYMER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo element doesn't exist at first so you have nothing to transition from.

Create a hidden default state with `opacity` or something and then when it gets toggled on it should fade into view.

**Example**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.wrapper:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 6px -3px rgba(252, 29, 0, 1);
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.wrapper.shadow:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Any hints on how to do that Adam? I haven't delved into pseudo elements much at this point.

Comment: @physicsboy - There's many different ways. I've added an example above. You basically just need the pseudo element to exist and you transition into the visible state.

Comment: FANTASTIC! I'd been struggling with this for over a week! 
I could understand what you meant by it needing to be present before it could be used, but wasn't sure how to do it. Top man!

Comment: No probs. Pseudo elements are a bit different if you've not used them before

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798010/css-transitions-with-before-and-after-pseudo-elements),

> You just need to leverage the often forgotten **inherit** value [..] we can't (yet) directly target pseudo-elements with custom animations.

Meaning that you need to place the **transition: 2s all;** inside a **.wrapper .shadow** selector

Comment: Could you help me out a little more with how to implement this please?
I have seen your source's edited fiddle showing them using "inherit" to gain from the parent, but I'm either not using it properly or it's just not working.

Please see the original question for an updated CodePen.