# How can I apply .rotate() mixing to an <i> Icon Glyph element of Bootstrap?

Tags: css, rotation, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `<i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>` and what I would like to achieve is to rotate it 90 degrees. Although the rest of mixins like `.scale()` work, rotate is not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you do this with pure css? http://jsfiddle.net/EBXPn/ works for me.

Comment: @Tim just add that as an answer.. :) Works fine..

Comment: @Lipis as you suggested, now an answer.

Comment: @Tim this is very nice and works, but it would be more elegant and flexible to do it by using the lessCSS function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an result of @Lipis comment, here is my comment explained in an answer.

Pure CSS solution:

```
<i class="icon-search" id="rotate"></i>

#rotate {  
  -webkit-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(120deg);
  /* filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1.5); */
  -ms-transform:rotate(120deg);        
}
```

Or using Bootstrap's mixins and LessCSS:

```
#rotate {  
  .rotate(120deg); 
}
```

Keep in mind older browsers don't support this css.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBXPn) for a demo.

Comment: @Chris-Top I think using Bootstrap's mixins you can simply write `.rotate(120deg);`, so please verify and then probably just updating the answer for Bootstrap specific thingy..

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do a transform on a pseduo element (like :before), which is how icon fonts often are implemented. With Bootstrap's glyphs, there's background-image:url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png"); (like in that jsfiddle demo). Also see this: [Applying WebKit transitions to Pseudo Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873261/applying-webkit-transitions-to-pseudo-elements) and this: http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/