# CSS transition on pseudo elements in Chrome

Tags: html, css, webkit

How can I make a CSS transition work on a pseudo element?

Sample:

```
<div class="foo" data-foo='baz'>bar</div>
<div>hover below for the working (non-pseudo) effect</div>
<div class="tar" data-foo='arrr'>nyan</div>
```

Styles:

```
.foo {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #fcc;
}

.foo:after {
    margin-left: 4px;
    content: 'hoot';
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.foo:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}




.tar {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #fcc;
}

.tar {
    margin-left: 4px;
    content: 'hoot';
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.tar:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/sdzUp/1/**

This seems to work only on firefox (with its appropriate prefix)

Comment: I don't believe transitions are (yet) supported on pseudo-elements in Webkit. See '[Transitions and Animations on CSS generated content](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/).'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying WebKit transitions to Pseudo Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873261/applying-webkit-transitions-to-pseudo-elements)

Comment: there'a comment in there mentioning that this was fixed, but the bug still persists

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

**HTML**

```
<div class="foo" data-foo='baz'>bar <font>hoot</font></div>
<div>hover below for the working (non-pseudo) effect</div>
<div class="tar" data-foo='arrr'>nyan</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.foo {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #fcc;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.foo font{
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.foo:hover font{
    opacity: 1;
}
.foo:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.tar {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color: #fcc;
}
.tar {
    margin-left: 4px;
    content: 'hoot';
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
.tar:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/sdzUp/5/

Comment: not the idea. I need it to work on pseudo elements because I'm using data-attributes for content