# CSS transition width on :after element

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm having some trouble transitioning the with opening in this element. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vvscq/1625/).

```
#control:after{
    content:"R";
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:10px;
    height:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 2s linear;
    -ms-transition: width 2s linear;
    -o-transition: width 2s linear;
    transition: width 2s linear;
    font-family:helvetica
}

#control:hover:after{
    content: "REGGI";
    width:auto;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Here you can find some information why It not working on Chrome even if you change `width` value to static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873261/applying-webkit-transitions-to-pseudo-elements/9871077#9871077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done CSS ONLY without he psudo http://jsfiddle.net/vveST/

```
a{
    text-decoration:none
}

#control{
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:10px 15px;
    height:20px;
    width:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:helvetica;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.1s ease;
    -ms-transition: width 0.1s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.1s ease;
    transition: width 0.1s ease;
}

#control .b{
    display:none;
}

#control:hover .a{
    display:none;
}

#control:hover .b{
    display:inline-block;
}

#control:hover{
    width:55px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There was a long-standing bug in WebKit where pseudo-elements could not be transitioned, however, it is now fixed and I don't think that that is the problem here.

The problem here is that you cannot transition to `auto` values. You need to use an absolute value.

You also have to set an initial value:

```
#control:after{
    content:"R";
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:10px;
    height:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 2s linear;
    -ms-transition: width 2s linear;
    -o-transition: width 2s linear;
    transition: width 2s linear;
    font-family:helvetica

    width: 50px;
}

#control:hover:after{
    content: "REGGI";
    width: 100px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with static value instead of auto? Because I yes and it still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/Vvscq/1627/

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: me Chrome. And yes I checked on other and it's working on FF but you are wrong by telling `...it is now fixed` -.-

Comment: @WooCaSh It is fixed in WebKit, whether the fix has made its way into Chrome is another matter.

Comment: I think you probably also have to set an initial value. I updated my answer with that code.

Comment: @RossPenman It's still not working =[ to be honest I don't need the :after would be easier but not necessary, working on another solution now will get back

Comment: I've got it! The transition breaks when you change the `content` property. Why don't you set it to be `"REGGI"` before the `:hover` event, and then use `overflow: hidden` to obscure it? Then you can just change the width on `:hover`.