# CSS3 Spinning Animation doesn't work on Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, css, animation

Can anybody tell why this CSS3 Animation refuses to work when I test it on my Iphone? It works fine on Chrome.

```
    .heartbeat:after {
        content: "\f118";
        font-family: fontAwesome;
        font-size: 50px;
        color: rgb(0, 156, 255);
        -webkit-animation: spin 1000ms ease 0s infinite normal;
        -moz-animation: spin 1000ms ease 0s infinite normal;
        -ms-animation: spin 1000ms ease 0s infinite normal;
        -o-animation: spin 1000ms ease 0s infinite normal;
        animation: spin 1000ms ease 0s infinite normal;
    }

    @-ms-keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    @keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

I checked similar questions and tried to replace `from` and `to` with `0%` and `100%`, and rotate 180 degrees at a time, use rotate3d instead; didnt work.

Comment: Have you tested it on Desktop Safari? My hunch is it could be something to do with Safari rather than iOS specific issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying WebKit transitions to Pseudo Elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873261/applying-webkit-transitions-to-pseudo-elements) . Apparently this is now fixed in Chrome but not yet Safari https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-animationstransitions-bug-fixed-in-webkit/

Comment: you're using webkit prefixing on a moz animation? As with the -ms- prefixing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reason behind this. You have an error here:

```
  @-ms-keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    @keyframes spin { 
        from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
```

---

Notice anything here, for example?

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

You're using a `-moz-` keyframe, which is fine, but notice anything else?

How about the `-webkit-` prefix on the transform?

---

So, in essence, this would become:

```
@-moz-keyframes spin { 
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Repeat this for your other keyframes and this should sort out a problem or two...

Comment: How weird is this. I am using this same animation method to solve my issue of my spinner not spinning with iOS and made sure the prefixes were right. At first my spinner is display:none but when I click a button it triggers a css change to display:block  ... but doesn't rotate. While the page is processing (its a long server process), if I navigate away (e.g. google.com) and then tap BACK then suddenly it IS in the middle of animation.

Comment: changed it to change the visibility instead of display. And it worked. Just putting this out there for anyone with future issues.