# Text animation not working in Safari

Tags: css, animation, text, keyframe

I have a text spinner/rotator on my website,

link: http://jaaplangenberg.nl/index2.php

The problem is, on my IPhone it doesnt work, instead of the spinning word is all I see is empty space. 
EDIT: I see it doesnt work on Safari in general (also browser)

I can't figure out what is wrong!

This is the code:

```
<p class="slogan">Je <span id="spin"></span> <br />van betekenis.</p>
```

And the css:

```
#spin:after {
  content:"";
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: spin 10s linear infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: spin 10s linear infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: spin 10s linear infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: spin 10s linear infinite; /* IE 10+ */
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { content:"merk"; }
  50% { content:"missie"; }
  100% { content:"verhaal"; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { content:"merk"; }
  50% { content:"missie"; }
  100% { content:"verhaal"; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS3 Spinning Animation doesn't work on Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854967/css3-spinning-animation-doesnt-work-on-iphone)

Comment: when i put -webkit- in front of "content" it doesnt work either..